# error with utf8 data

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, socket.io

I'm trying to create a very simple chat application with socket.io. It worked fine but utf8 data. I got an error when I tried to send some messages containing utf8 content.

```
   Error: Invalid continuation byte
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at readContinuationByte (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engin
    e.io\node_modules\engine.io-parser\node_modules\utf8\utf8.js:127:9)
        at decodeSymbol (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\nod
    e_modules\engine.io-parser\node_modules\utf8\utf8.js:167:12)
        at Object.utf8decode [as decode] (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modu
    les\engine.io\node_modules\engine.io-parser\node_modules\utf8\utf8.js:201:17)
        at Object.exports.decodePacket (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_module
    s\engine.io\node_modules\engine.io-parser\lib\index.js:150:17)
        at WebSocket.Transport.onData (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules
    \engine.io\lib\transport.js:102:24)
        at WebSocket.onData (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io
    \lib\transports\websocket.js:75:30)
        at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at Receiver.self._receiver.ontext (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_mod
    ules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:697:10)
        at Receiver.opcodes.1.finish (F:\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\
    engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:397:14)
    Program node chat.js exited with code 8
```

How could I fix it?

//Edit

I tried sending these characters `æøå` from server and it output `Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥` on client side. It seems to be `ANSI` characters.

Comment: Is your .js file utf-8 encoded? It's important

Comment: Yes. I use NotePad++ and this file `encode in UTF-8 without BOM`.

Comment: Can you show the utf-8 content which causes the error? Is it a regular latin text or some kind of exotic?

Comment: `á`, `ú`, `é` or something like these, even with those single characters.

Comment: I've added some more infomation about this error. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Hm, I just tried using these symbols in my project. I tried to paste them to my `server.js`, also tried to send them from the textarea to other client via socket.io server, and everything works fine. I think that problem is beyond socket.io. Maybe you retrieve this text from something like DB, text files, etc. If so, ensure that they have right encoding. For example in `mysql` it can be done with this query: `"SET NAMES utf8"`. Also try to add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the `<head>` of your HTML file in case if problem text goes from an HTML form

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm. After hours of searching, I found this post, https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io-parser/issues/21. I just forgot to update my socket.io on client side. ~~

Comment: You're welcome :) Could you write your last comment as an answer? I'm sure it will be very helpful for those who face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, I found [this post](http://github.com/Automattic/engine.io-parser/issues/21). I just forgot to update my socket.io on client side.